# How to check harddisk type?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

```
[root@testing ~]# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                     274597936  23881492 236542648  10% /
/dev/sda1               101086     12964     82903  14% /boot
tmpfs                   770076         0    770076   0% /dev/shm
```

How to check the hard disk type or model number if I can?

I tried

```
[root@testing ~]# hdparm -i /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[root@testing ~]# smartctl -H /dev/sda1
smartctl version 5.38 [x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

SMART Health Status: OK
```

What else can I do? I need to know if it's SATA or SCSI, if it's RAID or the brand names like Seagate that kind of thing..

Comment: Open system case, you will get the details for sure

Comment: Have you tried `hwinfo --disk`?

Answer (score 7):

try `lshw -class disk -class storage` command . it will show detailed information on disk configuration. you will get the vendor,type of disk etc all information.